# how to resolve the error 233 in sql sever 2005 in windows 7

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-7

I m creating a new login using sql server authentication.

a new login is created.

when i m tring to login with sql server authentication there is an error

```
Cannot connect to (SERVER NAME) i.e name\sqlexpress
```

Additional Information:

```
"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error 
occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, 
error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL 
Server, Error: 223)"
```

I hv already enabled all the protocols running as administrater. set authentication mode both windows and sql sever authentication

Comment: What does the SQL Server log say? Have you restarted SQL Server since changing things?

Comment: Is the SQL Server service running?

Comment: then is your connection string correct?

Comment: One thing on the restart which **still** catches me out. If you do it in SSMS it pops up an "Are you sure" dialogue which can get hidden behind SSMS and you don't see it until you close down!

Comment: Visit this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277
perfect solution is there....
I got it from there only............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution of this error which solve this issue i would like to answer here because if anybody find this question than it will also finds its answer and its time not wasted.

Click on Start menu > Programs > Microsoft Sql Server > Configuration Tools

Select Sql Server Surface Area Configuration.

Now click on Surface Area configuration for services and connections

On the left pane of pop up window click on Remote Connections and Select Local and Remote connections radio button.

Select Using both TCP/IP and named pipes radio button.

click on apply and ok.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons this error message appears.  Try each of the following to see if it solves the problem:

1. Restart the SQL Service - sometimes configuration changes require a restart to take effect.
2. Check that Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocls are enabled from the SQL Server Configuration Manager
3. Use Surface Area Configuration Manager to ensure that remote connections are allowed if trying to connect from a remote machine.
4. Ensure your firewall (on the client and the server) is not blocking connections
5. Ensure the account has a default database defined.
6. Ensure the account is not disabled - if you have set up the account to enforce password policies then too many failed logins may disabled the account.
7. Double check that you are using the correct password - even to the extent of reseting it.

Comment: Thanks 
how to Use Surface Area Configuration Manager to ensure that remote connections are allowed?